# How to set custom runtime path of assembly in deps.json file permanently?

Tags: c#, .net, json, dll, csproj

I change directory of my .dlls from

> netcoreapp2.2 to netcoreapp2.2/lib

Then my application don't start because

> Error:
>     An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'MyAssembly', version: '1.0.0'
>       path: 'lib/MyAssembly.dll'

Then I discovered that if I put path of this assembly in deps.json file it works correctly:

> "runtime": {
>             "D:\Repos\MyApp\MyProject\bin\Release\netcorepp2.2\lib\MyAssembly.dll": {}
>   }

But after rebuilt or cleaning and building solution, this file is overwriting.

- I want to know how can I put it permanently to my deps.json file?
- I    want to put path just like lib\MyAssembly.dll not full path like
  in    example.

Comment: Try adding AppName.runtimeconfig.dev.json file and specify 'additionalProbingPaths' there. See: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/

Comment: When you say `I change directory of my .dlls from`, what do you mean? They are your project dll? External dlls? Where did you set the location change? Only in the file system?

Comment: I change directory of external dlls. I'm moving them with post-built event. Maybe, existing another solution to move them?